# “The town is (located) 20km southeast of city X”

Tags: passive-voice, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases, subject-complement

> The town is (located) 20 km southeast of city X

Is *southeast* an adjective being modified by *of city X* (an adverb phrase) and having *20 km* (an adverb) modifying it?

Or is *20km* an adjective modifying *southeast* (a noun) and *of city X* an adjective phrase modifying *southeast*?

Does having *located* change anything?

Please explain the word classes, phrases, and which is modifying which.

I am really confused with prepositions (space/time words). I know that a prepositional phrase can be either an adjectival or adverbial phrase.

Comment: Hello Alienxalienz and welcome to ELL! Unfortunately, you have asked many questions at once, which is off-topic on this site. Please decide which single aspect of that sentence you really want to know about, and edit out all the other questions. Your first two questions are really one, so that's fine, but asking about "located" is a separate question. We do not completely analyze entire sentences, as you ask us to do after that.

Answer (score 0):

You could construe "southeast" either as a predicate adjective (modifying "the town") or as an adverb (modifying either "is" or "located"). In either case, "20km" and "of city X" can both be considered to modify "southeast" (so they function adverbially).

All of that is true either with "located" or without it.